# Linux does not boot anymore after switching disks in SATA ports

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssd, sata

I have two disks. One SSD with Debian 10 and an HDD with Windows 10. This morning I installed Debian 10 on the SSD while the SSD was plugged in SATA1. After that I shut the PC down, plugged the disk out and connected my HDD on SATA2. I installed Windows there. However I switched back (plugging the HDD from SATA2 off and inserting the SSD in SATA1) and now nothing is happening, no OS is being found in my UEFI.

EDIT: The SSD gets detected by the mainboard. It is shown in my UEFI with the device name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it! Turns out this was a problem of my Debian boot partition. I inserted a Debian install CD, went to rescure options and then installed the bootloader to a backup location for the EFI. After a reboot everything is working fine now and I can access my OS again!